# Parse tags in XML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, solr, xml-parsing

Need to parse the XML and fetch specific tag's value

We need to display just the tags where correct words are placed - "sports" and "secure" which are appearing in tag **`<str name="word">WORD</str>`** in below XML

**XML**

```
<response>
    <lst name = "responseHeader">
        <int name status>0</int>
        <int name QTime>3</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response",numFound="0",start="0"/>
    <lst name="spellcheck">
      <lst name="suggestions">
        <lst name="sporsts">
          <int name="numFound">1</int>
          <int name="startOffset">0</int>
          <int name="endOffset">5</int>
          <int name="origFreq">0</int>
          <arr name="suggestion">
            <lst>
              <str name="word">sports</str>
              <int name="freq">1</int>
            </lst>
          </arr>
        </lst>
        <lst name="secuer">
          <int name="numFound">1</int>
          <int name="startOffset">6</int>
          <int name="endOffset">17</int>
          <int name="origFreq">0</int>
          <arr name="suggestion">
            <lst>
              <str name="word">secure</str>
              <int name="freq">1</int>
            </lst>
          </arr>
        </lst>
      </lst>
      <bool name="correctlySpelled">false</bool>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Currently, using ajax to fetch the data by calling ajax as mentioned here :
In the ajax call :

```js
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: solrurl,
   dataType: "xml",
   cache: false,
   success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
         },      
     error : function(data)
     { 
          alert(Contact the Solr Admin);
     }
});
```

Tried using response.spellcheck.suggestions[0], but its throwing error - tried by putting other parameters as well, but it didn't work!

Could anyone please suggest or advise on getting just the words sports and secure in an array.

Comment: after success function, you can use use $(this).find('Str').text() and store it to some var. It should fetch data between <str></str> tags.

Comment: @sagarthapa Its coming empty - I tried with  $(this).find('Str').text() ,  $(this).find('str').text() ,  $(this).find('word').text() - It didnt work !!

Comment: hmm...okay now try changing success: function(data) to success: function(xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code and have checked it and it works fine.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Values = new Array();
    $.get("chckvar.php",{},function(xml){
        $("str",xml).each(function(i){
            Values.push($(this).text());
        });
        console.log(Values)
    });
});
```

In the browsers console window you would be able to see the output as

```
["sports", "secure"]
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Debaditya - does the solution above provided helped you